# active record with ruby (not rails)

Tags: ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I am using active record with ruby (but not rails).  I am using sqlite3 which has a test.db on file (not just in-memory).  When I run the following code snippet using user.create, it complains about argument error (and when I use use.save, it throws an active record exception. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?  Thanks

```
    require 'rubygems'
    gem 'activerecord'

    require 'sqlite3'
    require 'active_record'

    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDERR)
    #ActiveRecord::Base.colorize_logging = false

    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      :adapter => 'sqlite3',
      :host => "localhost",
      :database => 'test.db'
    )

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        #attr_accessible :email, :full_name
      attr_accessor :email
      attr_accessor :full_name

    validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true

      def initialize(email, full_name)
        @email = email
        @full_name = full_name
      end
    end

    puts "full_name for user:"
    full_name = gets.chomp
    puts "email address:"
    email = gets.chomp
    user = User.new(email, full_name)
    #user.save
    user = User.create!(email: '', full_name: '')
```

**Exception in first case (with User.create!):**

```
main.rb:42:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) (ArgumentError)
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:50:in `create!'
        from main.rb:55:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could you please give the stacktrace of the exception ?

Comment: @JeanBob added - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is complaining about the `new` method. According to the documentation: (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html), you don't need the `initialize`, because when you inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`, you need to initialize your objects with a hash.

```
user = User.new({email: email, full_name: full_name})
# or
user = User.new(email: email, full_name: full_name)
# then
user.save
```

You need to drop the `initialize` and the `attr_accessor` from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to comment User#initialize method and create new user like this:

```
User.create! email: 'halk@mail.com', full_name: 'Halk'
```

**Explanation**

When you declare AR model by heritage from `ActiveRecord::Base` class you don't need to define your own `#initialize` method. But you do. When you call `User::create!` method, you pass only **one** argument - `Hash` with two pairs (with email and full_name keys). But `User#initialize` define **two** parameters - email and full_name separately. So Ruby exception raise and talk about it:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: for some reason, that syntax gave me an error - maybe I did something wrong.  But your main point is correct

Comment: Oh, sorry, I pass `name` key instead of `full_name`. Edited.